# Why I have this output when I open anaconda?

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

```
C:\Users\user>python C:\Users\franc\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  
1>temp.txt
C:\Users\user>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt
C:\Users\user>del temp.txt
C:\Users\user>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
C:\Users\user>if errorlevel 1 (
 ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
 )
```

when I open anaconda, after have uptadated some packages I have the above output in Anaconda prompt, could it be a problem?

Comment: seems like the keras config file has been altered. you may want to check where the config file is. normally its ~/.keras in linux based systems(~=home folder). sorry not sure about Windows

Comment: Thank you, but I have Windows

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806075/error-when-installing-keras-in-anaconda-p-keras-backend-0temp-txt?rq=1 seems my same problem, but I don't find keras_activate.bat and keras_deactivate.bat

Comment: See this link. You'll be able to run Anaconda Prompt again:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54237245/8902456