# Anaconda Prompt Stuck/Closing after Keras installation

Tags: python, windows, cmd, keras, anaconda

So I recently downloaded keras through the anaconda prompt (I've downloaded other packages successfully). It actually worked, as I was able to import keras in Jupyter Notebook. However, now I get the following issue when I open the Anaconda Prompt:

```
C:\Users\[User Name]>python C:\Users\[User Name]\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\[User]': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\[User Name]>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\Users\[User Name]>del temp.txt

C:\Users\[User Name]>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
```

Things to Note:

- At first, I simply cannot type or enter anything into the window.
- After closing and reopening it, the same message opens up, but is followed by a bunch of text I can't read because the window immediately closes afterward.
- In the error message provided, the third line has [User] instead of user. That is because my users folder name on my computer is FirstName LastName. There is a space which I'm wondering might be the issue.
- I don't want to uninstall anaconda, as I have a project due in a few days and don't want any installation/loss of data issues.

So, is my folder name having a space the root of the issue? If it is, how do I change it without messing up my computer? If it isn't, do you guys have any ideas of what is the solution to this? Thank you so much, I have two projects due in just a few days :(

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54327432/5929443

Answer (score 3):

After a few days of searching, I found an alternative solution.

1. Open Anaconda Navigator
2. Click on `Environments` tab ( as shown in the picture)[image]
3. Click `base(root)` (triangle icon) and then click on `Open Terminal`[image]

By using this solution, you'll be able to open `Anaconda Prompt` window and do whatever you want with `Anaconda Prompt`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes.  This is a `cmd.exe` parsing question.

```
python.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py" > temp.txt
```

Comment: The error I posted pops up automatically when I open Anaconda Prompt, and cannot be altered.

Comment: @AnthonyG. Fix the script that launches Anaconda then or pass your arguments to Anaconda quoted.  Assuming you're just typing `anaconda` at a `cmd` prompt: `where.exe anaconda` and fix that script.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to do that haha. Where would I go to fix the script that launches Anaconda, and how would I "fix" it?

Comment: @AnthonyG. First, how are you launching anaconda: clicking a shortcut?  If so, right-click it and view the properties, figure out what it's launching.

Comment: Yes, the Anaconda Prompt Shortcut. I looked at the properties. It's "Target" is: "%windir%\System32\cmd.exe" /K ""C:\Users\[User Name]\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Users\[User Name]\Anaconda3""

Comment: @AnthonyG. There you go.  Open that `activate.bat` file and figure out what to change based on my answer.

Comment: I opened up the text file and it contained this:    #!/bin/sh
_CONDA_ROOT="$(cygpath 'C:/Users/Anthony G/Anaconda3')"
\. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
_conda_activate "$@"
So, not quite sure what to do from here. When I open the batch file with the same name, the anaconda prompt opens with the same error I originally posted. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 : I opened activate.bat . Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

delete files in 
C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\etc\conda\activate.d

or you can reinstall/remove keras from anaconda navigator:
- right click env name
- start terminal
- ctrl-c to stop any batch job.