# can't use anaconda prompt after trying to install keras

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, prompt

I tried to install keras using Anaconda prompt some time ago. It didn't work, but I got it working using another method. However, now when I open Anaconda Prompt it shows

```
set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt
del temp.txt
python - c "import keras" 1>nul 2>&1
```

It then runs and some output comes up which I don't have time to read or screenshot and Anaconda Prompt closes. Does anyone know how to fix this? I have seen a few other questions for the same problem, but haven't seen any answers.

Comment: See this post. You'll be able to run Anaconda Prompt again: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54237245/8902456

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a way to fix this so had to reinstall Anaconda distribution and now it works fine.

Comment: I did the same. But have you tried to install keras again on this reinstalled Anaconda? I tried to install keras again. But, Anaconda prompt closes instantly.