# Why do I get this message while starting virtual environment in Windows PC

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

When I activate a virtual environment on my windows PC I get this message

```
  set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt
  del temp.txt
  python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
  if errorlevel 1 (
  ver  1>nul
  set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
  python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
   )
```

I could able to open my environment and work in it , but I would like to know why do I get this message

Thank you

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50814231/2570277

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a log. Since you get it when activating your virtual environment, it tells you how it's building it:

1. sets environment variable value from the file temp.txt
2. Once it's set deletes the file
3. Make a python import (with error control).

In short, it's just a standard message of a typical "build-something" application.